# How to connect 4 HDDs to a PICO SPU which has only one 4 PIN Molex?

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply

I want to exchange the PSU of my my HP ProLiant N40L Microserver with a [PICO PSU](https://www.alternate.de/Inter-Tech/Mini-ITX-PSU-160W-DC-DC-Adapter/html/product/1699398?sug=psu) which has 1x 24-Pin-ATX12V-2.x, 1x 4+4-Pin-12V, 1x 4-Pin-5,25", 1x 15-Pin-SATA connectors.

However, I have 4 HDDs so I would need 4x 4-Pin-5,25" and I am not sure if it is a good choice to daisy chain to many molex splitters.

Can I also use the other connectors with adapters to Molex to connect my HDDs?

What is the best option here?

Comment: Check power consumption of your hard drivers, find detailed PICO PSU information that gives max rating for each of the connectors, then you know how many and which harddisks you can connect to which connectors with which splitters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [1xMolex->2xMolex](https://www.amazon.de/AKYGA-AK-CA-15-Stecker-Buchse-Adapter/dp/B07TWFWQDC) and a [1xSATA->2xMolex](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002LBROAA) splitter in conjunction, although you should check wether your total wattage is still under 160W

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Well according to the specs of my HDD it sais they use 1,75A with 5V or 12V (+10% peak) https://www.tweaktown.com/reviews/8231/wd-red-10tb-nas-hdd-review/index.html
If I am not mistaken, so that means worst case 4 of them will need 88W. Which will leave 72W for the rest (mainboard, one 120mm fan) which should be enough I guess.